# How do I count the number of flips(new slides viewed) in a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, algorithm, view

I'm building a web-app that lets users make and embed slideshows.

Now this has a feature called 'flips' which essentially displays the number of clicks on the next button (So, if a slideshow has 10 slides, if the viewer views the entire thing, the flips will increase by +1 on each click on next and display flips as 1,2,3....(till)..10. if the flip count was 358 (say) before the viewer started viewing it, it'll go from 358, 359, 360....368 with every click. Hope you get the point).

Now, the simplest way to implement this would be to make a DB call every time someone clicks 'next'. So, it'll update the DB and display the updated value (i'm using ajax for this) but this will mean that a lot of DB calls will be made and that is not good for performance. Also, if multiple users are viewing the same slideshow at the same time, the increment wont be +1 for any one of those viewers. It'll be something random, more than 1.

Now, how do I implement this most efficiently. The accuracy of flips itself isn't that big of a deal. I can compromise on that. But DB calls need to reduce, definitely.

What would be the middle path to keep the DB calls down n accuracy decently correct. Algorithm idea people?

Comment: *" but appear as the sum total of all the views (click on next button) at that point in time."* So you increment what is in the database.... There is no algortihm here, if you want to keep track, you will need to send data to the server. Do you need everyone to have the exact counts all the time? If yes, than yes it is complex. If no, than is just like any page counter that has been coded since the 90s

Comment: Why do you think that making an Ajax call is not good for performance? There is really no other way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Set a cookie. Then on page load, check if cookie exists. If it does, increment a counter and store it to the cookie. Here is a little script you can build from:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script

Comment: OP wants a count of how many times anyone has viewed it. Not just a count of how many times the current user has viewed it.

Comment: Not at all what the OP wants... How does a cookie save clicks for every user on the site?

Comment: It dont. I thought he wanted to know how many times each user visits it.

Comment: I've updated the question to make myself clearer. The previous explanation was ambiguous.